# ggplot2 stat_summary transforms data first, which labels errorbars wrong in logarithmic scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matched "pre" and "post" dataset and would like to plot geometric mean and SD in a line plot in the logarithmic scale (see figure below). Since the `stat_summary()` function transformed the data and then did the calculation, the geometric mean and SD plotted in the left figure were incorrect. The geometric mean SD should be symmetric in the logarithmic scale, while it was not in the plot (Group "pre" in the left figure).

I understand that `coord_trans()` does not do the calculation and should do the job. However, the connecting line in the logarithmic scale is not straight, which looks a bit odd for visualisation.

**Is there a solution to plot Geometric Mean and SD calculated from raw data and also straight connecting lines in a log scale?**

```
data_raw = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
                      Group=c(rep("before",12),rep("post",12)),
                      Values=c(15,60,70,300,40,35,100,1520,102,172,141,103,1200,130,
                               118,158,199,5804,1258,4582,4052,3332,2202,5129))

data_sorted <- data_raw %>% arrange(ID, Group)

left=ggplot(data_sorted, aes(Group,Values))+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID),colour = "gray",linetype= 2,position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  geom_point(size = 1.2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar")+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))*exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))/exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

right=ggplot(data_sorted, aes(Group,Values))+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID),colour = "gray",linetype= 2,position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  geom_point(size = 1.2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar")+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))*exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))/exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  coord_trans(y="log10")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

ggarrange(left,right)
```

[image]

Just to point out the error for you, the actual geometric mean (thick crossbar) of the "post" group is >1000 (right figure). However, it shows <1000 in the left figure.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric mean in euclidean space is the same as the arithmic mean in log-space. Because the y-scale log-transforms your data, you can just convert your functions like `exp(mean(log(x)))*exp(sd(log(x)))` to `mean(x) + sd(x)` (recall that `exp(log(A) + log(B)) == A * B`).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(scales)

data_raw = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
                      Group=c(rep("before",12),rep("post",12)),
                      Values=c(15,60,70,300,40,35,100,1520,102,172,141,103,1200,130,
                               118,158,199,5804,1258,4582,4052,3332,2202,5129))

data_sorted <- data_raw %>% arrange(ID, Group)

left=ggplot(data_sorted, aes(Group,Values))+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID),colour = "gray",linetype= 2,position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  geom_point(size = 1.2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {mean(x)}, geom="crossbar")+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {mean(x) + sd(x)}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {mean(x) - sd(x)}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

right=ggplot(data_sorted, aes(Group,Values))+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID),colour = "gray",linetype= 2,position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  geom_point(size = 1.2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar")+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))*exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) {exp(mean(log(x)))/exp(sd(log(x)))}, geom="crossbar", width=0.4, size=0.1)+
  coord_trans(y="log10")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

ggarrange(left,right)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is so smart! All the best!